# Symptom checker with php-mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table 'Result':

[image]

there will be page where all symptomp's will be in Check box's. When anyone check some of them, and click SUBMIT button, then the page will redirect to an another page where it will show the possible result.

Possible Result: if (Headache, Temperature, Lightheadnes) is checked then the answere will be Pneomonia and Malarya. cause these symptom's are common in these two desease.

i have made the table. But cannot think of the query. Please anyone give me an idea/solution.

i am using php-mysql.

Comment: I would advise reading about normalization, before going into queries.

Comment: Tip: try to formulate a *technical* question. "Symptom checker" doesn't really say anything about what your question is about.

Comment: I agree with @ArtjomKurapov here, you should optimize your database first; a quick example: keeping the names this way causes redundancy (the string "Dizziness" appears 3 times in the table, etc); this thing would be accomplished by using a symptoms table, a diseases table and one that saves the relationship between the two (and will only use ids); this way the query will also be easier to write

Comment: Artjom, this schema may be in BCNF already.

Answer (score 2):

```
#tblDiseases - holds all disease names
######################################
diseaseID | disease     
-----------------------
1            Tifoyd        
2            Jondis    
3            Malarya
4            Pneomonia
5            Dengu


#tblSymptoms - holds all symptoms
#################################
symptomID | symptom
-------------------------
1            Headache        
2            Temparature    
3            Less Pain
4            Sever Pain
5            Mussle Pain


#tblRel - holds relation between diseases and symptoms
######################################################
relID  | dieaseID | symptomID
-----------------------------
1         1          1
2         1          2
3         3          1
4         3          2
5         3          3
```

When 3 symptoms are selected, the query would look like:

```
SELECT tblDiseases.disease
FROM tblRel 
   LEFT JOIN tblDiseases ON tblRel.diseaseID = tblDiseases.diseaseID
WHERE tblRel.symptomID = '1' AND tblRel.symptomID = '2' AND tblRel.symptomID = '3'
```

This will select diseases with the symptoms `Headache`, `Temperature` and `Less Pain`. So the query might show the result `Malaria` (based on the example).

I haven't tested this code. :)
I hope it would work.

Answer (score 1):

as others have already said optimize your db and then try. If for next option try:

```
$arrInput = $_POST['your check Var Name'];
$strSQL = sprintf("select * from result where symptom in ('%s')", implode("','", $arrInput));
$objRes = mysql_query( $strSQL );
```