# Not returning a resultset from a PHP db query

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have created a simple php mysql system that diagnose diseases based on symptoms. The user gets to select those symptoms that best describe his/her condition. The problem is that I can't get the query to work. I have the following tables:

1. `m_health_diseases` which holds the diseases with their unique ids (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, ....).
2. `m_health_symptoms` which holds the symptoms with their unique ids.
3. `m_health_relations` which holds the relations of diseases and their symptoms based on primary keys from the other two tables.

I'm not allowed to post images as a new user, but I hope you have an idea of the tables. Actually the tables are similar to this link post: [Symptom checker with php-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085461/symptom-checker-with-php-mysql) in the answer of Akhilesh B Chandran.

This is the SQL query:

```sql
SELECT m_health_diseases.DiseaseName 
FROM m_health_relations 
LEFT JOIN m_health_diseases 
  ON m_health_relations.DiseaseId = m_health_diseases.DiseaseId 
WHERE m_health_relations.SymptomId = '14' 
AND m_health_relations.SymptomId = '15' 
AND m_health_relations.SymptomId = '16' 
AND m_health_relations.SymptomId = '4'
```

The query above should return the disease: 'Common Cold' but it does not return any result set. I have tried changing the query in different ways, but still does not give me the result I need. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The problem in a nutshell is that you require `m_health_relations.SymptomId` to be several values at the same time, but it can only be one value. Paul's answer shows you how to do it.

Comment: Btw, is `SymptomId` an integer? If so, you don't need to quote your number values (14, 15, etc) - presently you're casting them to string unnecessarily, which will make your queries slower.

Comment: FYI, if you have `JOIN Foo ON Foo.same_name = Bar.same_name` it can be written as `JOIN Foo USING(same_name)`. It would with multiple `AND` conditions too: `USING(some_id,other_id)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the disease which has all the symptoms 14,15,16,4, you can join another copy of the m_health_relations table for each symptom you want to check.

```
SELECT d.DiseaseName 
FROM m_health_diseases d
INNER JOIN m_health_relations s1 ON (s1.DiseaseId = d.DiseaseId)
INNER JOIN m_health_relations s2 ON (s2.DiseaseId = d.DiseaseId)
INNER JOIN m_health_relations s3 ON (s3.DiseaseId = d.DiseaseId)
INNER JOIN m_health_relations s4 ON (s4.DiseaseId = d.DiseaseId)
WHERE
s1.SymptomId = 14 AND
s2.SymptomId = 15 AND
s3.SymptomId = 16 AND 
s4.SymptomId = 4;
```

If you imagine the result without the where clause, you have every disease with every 4-way combination of its symptoms, and the where clause selects a specific combination (if it exists).

Because I've used the same table several times, I've used table aliases for each table, which makes the query easier to read too.

Also, note I used INNER rather than LEFT join, since you are not interested in any null results.

Comment: Thanks Paul for your reply, but I tested the query and it returns an error: #1054 - Unknown column 'm_health_diseases.DiseaseName' in 'field list'. The column does exist, so what is the problem!!

Comment: @Manu I used different symptom ids to refer to a particular disease that have those symptoms in the m_health_relations table. The query that you suggested gives out all the diseases with symptomId= '14' but not a particular disease with a combination of various symptoms.

Comment: Sorry, because I used the table alias 'd', you would need to use that to refer to the m_health_diseases table. Amended.

Comment: Then why didn't it work. I don't understand why the query is giving an error of unknown column while the column does exist!!

Comment: I just explained why, but let me elaborate. Table aliases let you refer to a table with another name. You might do that for clarity, to make a long table name shorter, or you might do it to disambiguate multiple copies of the same table used in query. I aliased the m_health_diseases table as 'd', which means if I want to refer to a column from that table, I can't use m_health_diseases.foo, but d.foo instead.

Comment: I understand about table aliases and how they are used; what i don't understand is the case that the query does not identify that the column: DiseaseName within the table: m_health_diseases which is aliased by: d does exist as can be seen in the error: #1054 - Unknown column 'm_health_diseases.DiseaseName' in 'field list'

Comment: @marlaw21 - are you sure you are no longer using `m_health_diseases` rather than `d` anywhere in the query? Put up your full query in a pastie.org, ping one of us here, and let's see it.

Comment: @Paul,@halfer. Actually now the query seems to work. I think Paul edited his query. And I retested it, and its now working. Thanks a lot guys for all your help.

Comment: I did say I amended it, but glad you've got it now!

Answer (score 1):

Another try,

Since your requirement is to fetch all those `DiseaseName` whose set of symptoms include all the symptoms mentioned by user, i would suggest you to add logic in your code to handle this, but one way of doing (although not optimized) this via SQL query would be:

Create a table as follows:

```
#tblRel - holds relation between diseases and symptoms
######################################################
relID  | dieaseID | symptomSet
-----------------------------
1         1          1, 2            //Store the symptom set sorted (let symptom set start with a space)
2         2          1, 2, 3
```

Now,

```
SELECT diseaseID from tblRel where symptomSet like (" 4,% 14,% 15,% 16"); // Sort input set also
```

This should work for any number of symptoms, but some logic would be required in your code to sort the input set.

Comment: Therefore, I can't use AND in my query to return a particular disease WHERE having a set of symptoms:SELECT m_health_diseases.DiseaseName 
FROM m_health_relations 
LEFT JOIN m_health_diseases 
  ON m_health_relations.DiseaseId = m_health_diseases.DiseaseId 
WHERE m_health_relations.SymptomId = '14' 
AND m_health_relations.SymptomId = '15' 
AND m_health_relations.SymptomId = '16' 
AND m_health_relations.SymptomId = '4'

Comment: Yes, you cannot use `AND` unless you join the way Paul has suggested. If you want to go with that then you have to join as many times as number of symptoms.

Comment: But the problem is that the query does not work, Even though, I did everything right. It returns an empty result set, while if you look at the relationships, it should give out Common Cold as the disease.

Comment: I tested the Paul's query and it returns an error: #1054 - Unknown column 'm_health_diseases.DiseaseName' in 'field list'. The column does exist, so what is the problem!!

Comment: This is an interesting solution, if not a very relational one! Presumably the symptomSet should be best stored like `,1,,2,,3,` to correctly delineate every symptom id (a comma on either side of every value). Then to do an AND you'd do `LIKE "%,1,%,3,%"`. Operations involving `OR` would just require multiple `LIKE` statements connected with `OR`. (Since this solution is a bit hacky, only use it if it is faster that Paul's approach, which is more elegant).

Comment: Thank you Manu for your suggested approach, I will try it and see if it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @halfer, i was thinking about the same bug in the solution. Have amended it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE m_health_relations.SymptomId = '14' 
AND m_health_relations.SymptomId = '15' 
AND m_health_relations.SymptomId = '16' 
AND m_health_relations.SymptomId = '4'
```

How can m_health_relations.SymptomId be 14 and 15 and 16 and 4 at the same time?

It should be `OR` or `m_health_relations.SymptomId in (14,15,16,4)`

Comment: I used different symptom ids to refer to a particular disease that have those symptoms in the m_health_relations table. The query that you suggested gives out all the diseases with symptomId= '14' but not a particular disease with a combination of various symptoms.